# I'm getting repetitive left click in java applications

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, java

Exactly what the title says. Whenever I start a Java application (I've tried with JRE 1.6.0.38, 1.6.0.35 and 1.7.0.13, 1.7.0.10), I get large number of left-click events, in the range of tens per second, making Java programs unusable.

This first appeared when I updated from Java 1.7.0.10, but after I downgraded jre and experimented with older releases of Java 1.6, problem is still there.

Note that this only happens in Java applications and applets.

So how do I solve this?

**Update**:

The problem only starts happening after first left mouse click in the application window. Until I actually click the mouse, everything is fine. Also it takes about a second for behavior to start.

I've noticed that programs which come with their own JRE run fine and are not affected by the issue. It could be that there's some Java setting hidden somewhere where I can't find it that's causing problems.

Comment: @Karan The problem seems to start after first mouse-click in the Java application. Also just in case my mouse decided it hates Java, I did try with another mouse and touchpad and they seem to hate it too :).

Comment: @Karan Now that you mentioned uninstallation... I've noticed that programs which ship with their own integrated JRE run fine. Maybe there are some traces left that I didn't pick up.

Comment: @Karan That solved the problem. Post the procedure as an answer or is it's a duplicate vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**JavaRa**](http://singularlabs.com/software/javara/) might help you in a situation like this:

> JavaRa is an effective way to deploy, update and remove the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). Its most significant feature is the JRE Removal tool; which forcibly deletes files, directories and registry keys associated with the JRE. This can assist in repairing or removing Java when other methods fail.

[image: 1]

Uninstall all JRE versions, run JavaRa if you have to, clean the registry with CCleaner (or manually if you're comfortable with it), reboot and reinstall the latest version of 64-bit JRE.